# Apply grok filters to logs already stored in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm using `syslog->logstash->elasticsearch->kibana` to visualize my logs. The stack is working fine so far. I have already a few thousand logs in elasticsearch. Now I decided to change some grok filters. Is there a way to process all logs again to be matched by the new filters?

I can think of somehow exporting the database and adding that as a new input to logstash, but this would be kind of complicated.
I'm looking for an easy one click solution, because I'm likely going to change some filters in the future. I could not find any easy solution so far. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, there's no one-click solution. You'd have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use elasticsearch 5.0. Then you could run the logs through an `ingest` pipeline.